# How to use the webbrowser from a function within another class file?

Tags: c#, browser

This is my Program.cs

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InputSimulator IS = new InputSimulator();
        IS.SimulateTextInput("login", "username");
        IS.SimulateTextInput("lpass", "password");
        IS.SimulateButtonClick("login");
    }
```

This is my InputSimulator.cs

```
namespace Functions
{
    class InputSimulator
    {
        public void SimulateTextInput(string attName, string attValue)
        {
            Form1 mainForm = new Form1();
            HtmlElementCollection col = mainForm.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

            foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
            {
                if (element.GetAttribute("name").Equals(attName))
                {
                element.SetAttribute("value", attValue);
                }
            }
        }

        public void SimulateButtonClick(string attName)
        {
            Form1 mainForm = new Form1();
            HtmlElementCollection col = mainForm.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

            foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
            {
                if (element.GetAttribute("value").Equals(attName))
                {
                    element.InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason it gives me a NullReferenceException and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong as it doesn't give me any direct errors. The point where it goes wrong is when I click the button then at the following line:

```
HtmlElementCollection col = mainForm.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If I put the functions from InputSimulator directly into Program.cs it works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new form instance, that is hidden (not Visible) and webBrowser1 is not initialized, therefore Document is null. If you like to use you existing Form1 instance you can either pass it as reference to this function or add to the constructor.

For example pass it as reference:

```
public void SimulateTextInput(Form1 mainForm, string attName, string attValue)
{
   //Form1 mainForm = new Form1();
   if(mainForm == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("mainForm");
   HtmlElementCollection col = mainForm.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

   foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
   {
      if (element.GetAttribute("name").Equals(attName))
      {
         element.SetAttribute("value", attValue);
      }
   }
```

}

add to constructor:

```
class InputSimulator
{
    Form1 mainForm = null;

    public InputSimulator(Form1 inputForm)
    {
        if (inputForm == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("inputForm");

        mainForm = inputForm;
    }

    public void SimulateTextInput(string attName, string attValue)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection col = mainForm.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("name").Equals(attName))
            {
                element.SetAttribute("value", attValue);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SimulateButtonClick(string attName)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection col = mainForm.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("value").Equals(attName))
            {
                element.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    }
}
```